# How do I pass different value to each thread in ExecutorService?

Tags: java, arrays, multithreading, executorservice, runnable

Lets say I have an array `num_array = [0,1,2,3,4...30]`

and I have a multi-threading function like this

```java
static void multiThreadFunct (int[] num_array) {
    ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(25);
    try {
        Runnable r = new functToBeMultithreadded(arg1, arg2);
        executor.execute(r);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("err");
    }
    executor.shutdown();
}
```

I wanted to know how I can pass `num_array[0]` to `thread 1` and `num_array[1]` to `thread 2` ... `num_array[24]` to `thread 25`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just loop over the array and pass each runnable the element:

```
ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(25);
for (int num : num_array) {
    try {
        Runnable r = new FunctToBeMultithreadded(num);
        executor.execute(r);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        ...
    }
}
executor.shutdown();
```

Note that you should not assume the order of elements will correspond to the order of threads created in the pool. That's implementation dependent.

Comment: would this not create 25 threads for each number in `num_array` ?

Comment: @ShashankSetty It depends (at least on what the runnable does). The execute method's [Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/Executor.html#execute(java.lang.Runnable)) states:  "The command may execute in a new thread, in a pooled thread, or in the callingthread, at the discretion of the Executor implementation."